# Odd history of OAuth 2 device flow

Tags: oauth

OAuth 2 device flow has an odd history. It's found in [early versions](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-06) of the RFC, but was then taken out seemingly without an explanation I could find. Recently, a new [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-device-flow) was proposed specifically to reintroduce it independently.

> The device flow is suitable for clients executing on devices that do
> not have an easy data-entry method and where the client is incapable
> of receiving incoming requests from the authorization server
> (incapable of acting as an HTTP server).

The other flows do not cover the scenario addressed by device flow so it has utility. [Google supports it](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices) and has an example of it in action. Can anyone shed any light on why device flow was dropped from the [OAuth 2 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) - are there security concerns we should know about?

Comment: Just noticed in https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-device-flow Appendix A.  Acknowledgements.
   The -00 version of this document was based on draft-recordon-oauth-
   v2-device edited by David Recordon and Brent Goldman.  The content of
   that document was initially part of the OAuth 2.0 protocol
   specification but was later removed **due to the lack of sufficient
   deployment expertise at that time**.  We would therefore also like to
   thank the OAuth working group for their work on the initial content
   of this specification through 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should just answer my own question after stumbling upon the reason - device flow was removed from the OAuth 2 specification:

> due to lack of sufficient deployment expertise at that time

Citation from [Appendix A: Acknowledgements - IETF OAuth device flow draft #01](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-device-flow-01#appendix-A).

Device flow enables a device (smart TVs, media consoles, digital picture frames, printers) to obtain user authorization by using a separate device because it is easier to enter credentials with a keyboard than say a remote control.

Draft now published as [RFC 8628](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8628).